# How can I get my python executable to open properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a simple program for a friend using python 3.7 and I want to send it to them as an executable where they don't need python to actually use it. The current issue is that, when I run it, the terminal will open but the moment it starts to run code it closes and doesn't open the tkinter window its supposed to. Any ideas?

Comment: Try exe creation first with a very simple hello world program. If you have problems you can ask here with precise information about your code and the way you created the executable.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller

Try:

```py
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller /path/to/yourscript.py
```